# Tensorboard weights histogram only last layer visible change

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorboard

I added a TensorBoard visualization to my network and noticed that only the outlier changes a lot. Why do the weights of the network not change a lot? This is especially visible in the overlay histograms.

**Histograms**
[image: weight histogram]
same but overlay view
[image: overlay]

My model

```
def neural_network_model(inputdata):
    """The blueprint of the network and the tensorboard information
        :param inputdata: the placeholder for the inputdata
        :returns: the output of the network?
            """
    W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", shape=[set.input, nodes_h1],
                         initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    B1 = tf.get_variable("B1", shape=[nodes_h1],
                         initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
    layer1 = tf.matmul(inputdata, W1)
    layer1_bias = tf.add(layer1, B1)
    layer1_act = tf.nn.relu(layer1)

    W2 = tf.get_variable("W2", shape=[nodes_h1, nodes_h2],
                         initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    B2 = tf.get_variable("B2", shape=[nodes_h2],
                         initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
    layer2 = tf.matmul(layer1_act, W2)
    layer2_bias = tf.add(layer2, B2)
    layer2_act = tf.nn.relu(layer2)

    W3 = tf.get_variable("W3", shape=[nodes_h2, nodes_h3],
                         initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    B3 = tf.get_variable("B3", shape=[nodes_h3],
                         initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

    layer3 = tf.matmul(layer2_act, W3)
    layer3_bias = tf.add(layer3, B3)
    layer3_act = tf.nn.relu(layer3)
    WO = tf.get_variable("WO", shape=[nodes_h3, set.output],
                         initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    layerO = tf.matmul(layer3_act, WO)

    with tf.name_scope('Layer1'):
        tf.summary.histogram("weights", W1)
        tf.summary.histogram("layer", layer1)
        tf.summary.histogram("bias", layer1_bias)
        tf.summary.histogram("activations", layer1_act)
    with tf.name_scope('Layer2'):
        tf.summary.histogram("weights", W2)
        tf.summary.histogram("layer", layer2)
        tf.summary.histogram("bias", layer2_bias)
        tf.summary.histogram("activations", layer2_act)
    with tf.name_scope('Layer3'):
        tf.summary.histogram("weights", W3)
        tf.summary.histogram("layer", layer3)
        tf.summary.histogram("bias", layer3_bias)
        tf.summary.histogram("activations", layer3_act)
    with tf.name_scope('Output'):
        tf.summary.histogram("weights", WO)
        tf.summary.histogram("layer", layerO)
    return layerO
```

My understanding of the training process is that the weight should get adjusted which barely happens in the images. The loss goes done however, I've trained the network for 10000 epochs so I expected a bit more change overall. Especially the lack of change in the weights I don't understand.

[image: img]

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with my neural net and have found that the majority of the loss is being consumed by the biases. Have you reached any conclusions by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue with the weight histograms in my neural network. Although Relu does deal with the vanishing gradient problem for your hidden layers, you should check your learning rate and ensure that the update to each variable is not too small. This is likely to cause close to zero updates, resulting in insignificant changes over time. You can simply check the gradients for each layer using the following snippet:

```
def replace_none_with_zero(tensor):
   return[0 if i==None else i for i in tensor]

with tf.name_scope('Gradients'):
   gradient_for_variable_of_interest=replace_none_with_zero(
                              tf.gradients(loss,[variable_of_interest]))
```

And then check your gradients in tensorboard by calling the tf.summary.histogram on the gradients.